# Taylor series for arctan(x)

Tags: functional-analysis

I am having a serious problem with the following example:

$$f(x) = \arctan(x).$$

The task is to calculate the taylor polynom of the third grade. This is easy and I solved it.

The second task is to get the lagrange error for  $$ x \le \frac{1}{10} .$$

I know that the equation for the error is $$ R(f,x,x_0) = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \cdot f^{n+1}(\xi) \cdot (x-x_0)^{n+1} $$ and that, applied to this specific example, can be written as:

$$ R(f,x,0) = \frac{1}{4!} \cdot f''''(\xi) \cdot x^4 .$$

I also found the fourth derivation, which is $$\frac{24x-24x^3}{(x^2+1)^4}.$$ I can also set $x = \frac{1}{10}$ to get the "worst case", but how can I find a good $ \xi ?$

I would be happy if you could help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should not really be thinking of finding some particular $\xi$ but rather, estimating how big $|f''''(x)|$ can be (BTW note the absolute value signs).  The more thought you put into this the better estimate you can get (maybe), but probably a rather crude estimate will be good enough, so it's best just to go with fairly simple ideas.  Here is one possibility.

Since $|x|<\frac1{10}$ we have
$$|x|>|x^3|$$
and so
$$|24x-24x^3|<|24x|+|24x|<\frac{48}{10}\ ;$$
also
$$|x^2+1|\ge1\ .$$
Therefore
$$\left|\frac{24x-24x^3}{(x^2+1)^4}\right|<\frac{48/10}{1^4}=4.8\ .$$
Hope this helps!

BTW I am assuming that $x_0=0$: you didn't say so but from your working that's what it looks like.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helps, but why can you say $$|24x - 24x^3| < |24x| + |24x|$$?

Comment: Triangle inequality, $|a-b|\le|a|+|b|$.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. Your solution is absolutely clear but do you have an idea to get a better estimation?

Comment: Not too hard: $|x-x^3|=|x||1-x^2|\le|x|$, and so $|24x-24x^3|\le\frac{24}{10}$, slightly better than above.  Anything better than this, I suspect, could be very difficult.